# regex to remove the matched word and the consecutive word

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove the word **Dr** and its consecutive word.
for eg

**Input**

> Financial disclosure of **Dr Kucher**
>   Patient 1 had adverse
>   events and **dr Bodendieck** supposes that patient 1 does not tolerate
>   milk
>  Drug accountability log and patient compliance.

In the above input pattern  i want to remove all the text highlighted in Bold

**Output**

> Financial disclosure of 
>   Patient 1 had adverse events and
>   supposes that patient 1 does not tolerate milk
>  Drug accountability
>   log and patient compliance.

the pattern I am using 
`/[(D|d)r]\s*(?=\w+)`

***According to my understanding***
 
**[(D|d)r]** should match "Dr" or "dr"
**\s***  should match blank spaces
**(?=\w+])** should match the immediate consecutive word.

Reference to pattern 
http://regex101.com/r/eU5yT8/2

However the above  pattern is not getting matched 
I am a newbie in forming regex. Please help me understand my mistake.thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
re.sub(r'\b[Dd]r\s+\w+', '', txt)
```

when you wrap in `(?=...)` it will look-ahead but will not *consume*, as in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html): `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will *match* `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`. That means it will not match `'Asimov'`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'Isaac (?=Asimov)', 'Isaac Asimov')
['Isaac ']
```

also, you need `[Dd]r` which means either `D` or `d` followed by `r`, or alternatively `(Dr|dr)`.

`\b` would specify a word boundary, otherwise, it will match `dr` at the end of a word (if we have such a word):

```
>>> re.sub(r'[Dd]r\s*\w+', '', 'xdr test')
'x'
```

You will need `\s+`, or otherwise it will match `dr` in the middle of the word:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b[Dd]r\s*\w+', '', 'drug')
''
```